# ASP.Net MVC5 set secure and HTTPOnly flags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to set the `httponly` and the `secure` flag to all the cookies of my site to pass the security scans of my customer.
The web.config is configured correctly I think

```
<system.web>
   <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />
```

And it is working for all the cookies I create inside my application, but not for google analitycs ones (I know I can not do anything about it) and what I suppose are the session cookies of asp.net (`ai_user` and `ai_session`).

[image]

Searching for this two cookies lead to nothing.
How can I force the `httponly` and `secure` flags?

I do not know if it is related, but I have also this rewrite rule

```
<rewrite>      
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I tried to disable it, but nothing changed

Comment: Have look at [this](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/how-to-mark-session-cookie-secure/) article hopefully it'll give you some ideas

Comment: I tried the code, but the two cookies do not appear in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon "ai_session" and "ai_user" cookies now with my project and I think they are from application insights. If you investigate further, please report back to community.

Comment: I discovered that too, but no luck till now in understanding how to put the httponly attribute

Comment: my guess is it is set from javascript that Microsoft serves

Answer (score 0):

HTTP only flag cannot be applied universally as that would prevent the XSRF-Token from being able to be leveraged and cause a security issue. Some of the cookies don't have the HTTPOnly flag because they are used by the front-end to facilitate access to the application (ai_session, ai_user, idsrv_session).

Answer (score -2):

The right way to require SSL is via a global filter

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
     filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
     filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
     filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

Comment: I tried also with RequireHttpsAttribute but no luck